# Full Featured iFrame w/ Forward/Back Buttons, URL Loader, etc

Tags: html, forms, iframe, button

Thanks for viewing my question. So, I have a question with iframes. I want an iframe that is almost like an actual browser. I need to make it have atleast a forward button, a back button, and a URL loader. I have accomplished this but it is not working well.
My Code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title> iFrame </title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function()
    {
      $('.frmSubmit').click(function(e)
      {
        $('#myIframe').attr('src', $('.frmUrlVal').attr('value'));
        e.preventDefault();
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <input type="text" value="http://"class="frmUrlVal">
    <input type="submit" class="frmSubmit" value="Go">
    <input type="button" VALUE="&lt; &lt; &nbsp; Back &nbsp;"  onClick="myIframe.history.back()"> 
    <input type="button" VALUE="Forward &nbsp; &gt; &gt;"  onClick="myIframe.history.forward()"> 
  </form>
  <iframe align="center" width="50%" height="50%" src="http://gravitate.webs.com" frameborder=yes scrolling="yes" name="myIframe" id="myIframe"> </iframe>
  <form>
```

A reload/cancel button would also be preffered. Maybe even a statusbar. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
  <title> iFrame </title>
  <script language="javascript"> 
   function LoadPage(){ 
     var objFrame=document.getElementById("myIframe"); 
     objFrame.src=document.getElementById("URL").value;
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="Clear:both;"> 
 <input type="text" value="http://amazon.co.uk" class="frmUrlVal" ID="URL">
 <input type="submit" class="frmSubmit" value="Go" onclick="LoadPage()">
 <input type="button" VALUE="&lt; &lt; &nbsp; Back &nbsp;"  onClick="myIframe.history.back()"> 
 <input type="button" VALUE="Forward &nbsp; &gt; &gt;"  onClick="myIframe.history.forward()"> 
</div>
<iframe align="center" width="100%" height="90%" src="http://amazon.co.uk" frameborder=yes scrolling="yes" name="myIframe" id="myIframe"> </iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank You!! now i'm trying to get an iframe with tabs. Thanks for the code!

Comment: In which browsers has this demo been tested? I tried running this demo in Chrome, and it didn't work for me at all.

Comment: @AndersonGreen appears the security regarding iframes has been updated since this demo.