# Embed web browser within web page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

With the help of the following code i am able to embed google search bar within my website

```
<iframe id="if1" width="100%" height="254" style="visibility:visible" src="http://www.google.com/custom?q=&btnG=Search"></iframe>
```

but it has certain drawbacks, user can't go back to the previous page and cannot perform more than one search at a time,

is there a way i can embed web browser within my web page ??

Comment: You can not implement web browser , at least easily, but you can implement google search easily following this https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/tutorial/implementingsearchbox

Comment: I just hope you understand that this will happen: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8700754/2191572

Comment: won't this violate cross origin policy?

Answer (score 1):

You should build de back/forward/etc. controls yourself using some javascript.

Checkout this post:
[Full Featured iFrame w/ Forward/Back Buttons, URL Loader, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863029/full-featured-iframe-w-forward-back-buttons-url-loader-etc)

And it will only work for pages on the same domain!