# Firefox Web Browser Inside a Laravel Web Application?

Tags: laravel, firefox, browser, proxy

I want to create a web application in Laravel. Which runs on the firefox browser. Inside this Laravel Application, I want another firefox browser (firefox browser inside a firebox browser) with the USA proxy. Access through Admin Panel.
Can you guide me with it?
Thanks

Comment: Probably have to use an iframe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863029/full-featured-iframe-w-forward-back-buttons-url-loader-etc

Comment: can we add a VPN in the <iframe>?

Comment: can we add web proxy on it ?